# Good real-world networking books

Tags: router, home-networking, hosting

Is there a good book out there about router configuration for the home user that hosts at home, has multiple IP addresses, etc.  Basically, router configuration for the power user.  Some of the topics may include things like Dynamic Routes, Static Routes, Port Triggering.

I'm NOT looking for a certification, so an in-depth TCP/IP book is NOT what I'm talking about here.  On the other end, I've read a few "home network" books, and they do not go enough in-depth.  They may touch on how to setup a router to get multiple computers on a network, but I (and others) need a book that tells one how to get a cable modem, three routers, and a switch to all work together.

I will mark the highest voted reply as answered after 5 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this one:

[Cisco Networking Simplified](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1587201992)

[Expanded Info](http://www.ciscopress.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=1587201992)

EDIT: Probably not what you're after but it's a half decent introduction to a lot on networking.

Comment: It looks a bit closer to the level I'm describing.  I will check this out out.  Thank you.  -Jess

Answer (score 0):

For online help, check [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/computers-software/home-networking.html) out.

For a book, check [this](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Home-Networking-For-Dummies-4th-Edition.productCd-0470118067.html) out.

Comment: I took a peak at both links and these are pretty high-level from what I can tell.  Specifically this link (http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/configure-a-router.html) only explains the home user that is just trying to get more then one computer on the internet.  The book(s) I'm searching for would be more about what the difference between static/dynamic routes, ip tables, and stuff like that.  Thank you.  -Jess

Answer (score 0):

Cisco Press has a few different titles under the general theme of "CCNA Companion Guides", which are fairly decent come-up-to-speed books. Here's a link to the [first one](http://www.ciscopress.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=1587132087). You can follow the heading links above the title on that page to find the others.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you, I will check this one out as well.